# group and sum columns that have the same name in different cases with pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe with lots of columns that have what would be the same name, except the casing is not consistent. Some columns are in all caps and need to be summed with the appropriate column. How can I combine all the these columns with the same name, keeping the appropriate casing for the column name in the end?

I only want to change the case if there is another column name that is exactly the same string in all ways except for the casing. In this example I wouldn't want to change the case of "JFK", but I would want to combine the values of "CARL" with "Carl".

**edit:**
I realized my first example table didn't have the any cases where there was a name in all caps that did not have a matching name in a different case so I added "JFK".

**Example df:**

| Carl | CARL | Carl Smith | David | John | JFK |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 3 | 7 | 4 | 2 | 9 |

**Desired output:**

| Carl | Carl Smith | David | John | JFK |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 4 | 7 | 4 | 2 | 9 |

Comment: This combines the columns but doesn't preserve the proper case. I might be able to save the column names after dropping the ones in all-caps then assign those names back. It would work for this example but maybe not my actual df

Comment: The desired output table shows the case that I want to preserve. I think for my actual use case the only issues are ones that are entirely capitalized

Comment: @d.b edited to clarify

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most of the other answers here don't take into account that there are some names in all-caps that I don't want to change the case of, such as "JFK". This clarification was a later edit so it must've slipped through the cracks.

I only want to change the column name if it is a duplicate after changing all column names to lowercase e.g. "CARL" would become a duplicate with "Carl" after both were lowercased but "David", "John", and "JFK" would not be duplicates even after lowercasing.

**My Solution:**

```
cols = pd.Series(df.columns)                                                     # "Carl", "CARL", "David", "John", "JFK"
cols_lower = cols.str.lower()                                                    # "carl", "carl", "david", "john", "jfk"
cols_duplicates = cols_lower.drop(cols_lower.drop_duplicates().index)            # "carl"

names_to_group = df.loc[:, cols_lower.isin(cols_duplicates).to_numpy()].columns  # "Carl", "CARL"
new_names = names_to_group.map(string.capwords)                                  # "Carl", "Carl"

name_dict = dict(zip(names_to_group, new_names))                                 # {"Carl": "Carl", "CARL": "Carl"}  
df = df.rename(columns = name_dict)                                              
df = df.groupby(df.columns, axis=1).sum(1)
df

# Output:
   Carl  Carl Smith  David  John  JFK
0     4           7      4     2    9
```

Answer (score 2):

You can groupby the columns:

```
import string
reduced = [string.capwords(x) for x in df]
df.groupby(reduced, axis=1).sum()
```

In one line:

```
import string
df.groupby(df.columns.map(string.capwords), axis=1).sum()
```

Output:

```
   Carl  Carl Smith  David  John
0     4           7      4     2
```

Comment: Easier to use `df.columns.str.capitalize()` I think: doesn't require `import string`

Comment: @not_speshal I didn’t try it, but I think `capitalize` only capitalizes the first letter, not every word.

Comment: Indeed, in that case `df.columns.str.title()`?

Comment: This works if all the correct output names are formatted the same way, but I realized my issue is slightly more complicated. I added one more column to my example df to clarify @Quang

Answer (score 1):

You could lower case the column names (or uppercase) and then group them together:

```
# lower all col names for coherence
df.columns = [x.lower() for x in df.columns]
# group columns with same name
df.groupby(level=0, axis=1).sum()
```